# Why is textFieldwithPlaceHolderText undefined for one view controller that conforms to UITextFieldDelegate?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have two UIViewController sublcasses, both of them conform to the UITextFieldDelegate protocol. IOW, I have these classes.

```
# MyVC1.h
@interface MyVC1 : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

# MyVC1.m
@interface MyVC1 () {
    // Private variable, so not a property
    UITextField *_myTextField;
}
@end

@implementation MyVC1

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _myTextField = [self textFieldwithPlaceHolderText:@"*Text"];
}
@end
```

*SAME CODE* for MyVC2 class, except of course the class name.

However, and this is the strange part, my code compiles for MyVC1, but NOT for MyVC2. For MyVC2, compiler says "No visible @interface for "MyVC2" declares the selector "textFieldwithPlaceHolderText". What am I missing for MyVC2? I've double- and triple-checked!

Comment: Where are you creating `textFieldwithPlaceHolderText`? Are you sure both of your classes have that method, because it sure isn't a `UITextFieldDelegate` method.

Comment: The ONLY #import in both controllers' .h file is #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>, I do import different *.h files in their respective *.m files, but those *.h files (imported in the .m files), only themselves #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>. NONE of my classes have that method defined. This even stranger now. IOW, why does it work at all, that is, for MyVC1?

Comment: Are you sure the .h for MyVC1 is extending UIViewController and not some other ViewController? And that it doesn't have the method defined somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's late, and I'm sleepy. MyVC1 defines the textFieldwithPlaceHolderText method, but NOT MyVC2. I cut/past the viewDidLoad section, but forgot to cut/paste the method. Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: Haha np. But hey, feel free to up vote my answer and Jsdodgers original comment, not a time waste that way ;)

Answer (score 0):

Like Jsdodgers said, textFieldwithPlaceHolderText is not a method of UITextFieldDelegate. Check your #imports section on both controllers - maybe VC1 imports a category for UIViewController class that adds that method to it. A category import would look like this: #import "UIViewController+**_**.h"

Comment: Please see my comments above.

Answer (score 0):

copy the method  "textFieldwithPlaceHolderText" in myVc2.h in interface a
and implement in myvc2.m if i post anything wrong sorry for that